# xcode8 beta4 not generating the managedObjectContext

Tags: core-data, xcode8, encrypted-core-data-sql

I am using a blank core data proj and trying to copy the code from this examples.

https://www.and
rewcbancroft.com/2015/02/18/core-data-cheat-sheet-for-swift-ios-developers/

As there is no managedContext i am not able o proceed.

I am new to IOS programming. Please can anybody share me a simple example that i can start with. But i need it with Xcode8 beta4 version.
I tried many other examples but once i convert them to my current version they are not working.

[image]

Comment: Before doing anything else, **please** update to the released version of Xcode 8. Beta 4 isn't even the last beta; you're using software which **by definition** may still not work right.

Comment: I agree with you. I will install the non beta version and try.

Comment: I just installed Xcode8 released version still i see the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message reads:

> Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'managedObjectContext'

What this means is that *somewhere* (your screenshot does not show where) you are attempting to assign a value to a property named `managedObjectContext`, on an instance of your `ViewController` class. Except that this class doesn't have a property named `managedObjectContext`, so Swift complains and doesn't compile.

This is not actually a Core Data question-- it's basic Swift. It would happen for any attempt to assign a value to a nonexistent property.

You *probably* (again, your screenshot does not provide enough detail to be sure) need to create this property on your view controller class, with type `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: I was not aware how to do that. 
Few days back i created the subclass for managedObjectContext from the editor. Now i am using a separate controller to save and get the data.